# How to slice image by broadcasting slices? Error: 'only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index' in python?

Tags: python, numpy, slice, array-broadcasting

I have a simple task:
I have an image and an array of points.  For each point I want to slice boxes out of the image.

I can do this in a for loop, but for thousands of points it is very slow, so I need to do this without loops.  I'm trying to broadcast arrays to the slice values.  Here's some minimal code that illustrates the problem:

```
import numpy as np
frame = cv2.imread("input.png")
pts = np.array([[10,20],
                [30,40],
                [50,60]])  #and thousands more
x1s = pts[:, 0]
y1s = pts[:, 1]
x2s = x1s + 5
y2s = y1s + 5
cutouts = frame[x1s:x2s,y1s:y2s]
```

which gives me the error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Why?  The slices are all 1d arrays of integers (scalars).  This should work.  What is wrong, and how do I do it right?

Other stackoverflow posts about this error seem to have nothing to do with slicing or broadcasting.

Edit: To be clear, the point array will be thousands of points.  I want an array of thousands of 5x5 slices, one for each point.  So a slice starting at (10,20), another slice starting at (30,40), etc etc.

Edit2: People are saying things like you can't broadcast on a 2d array.  Yet *this* works, which is the same concept.  Why?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
frame = np.arange(50).reshape(5,10)
pts1 = np.array([1,2,3])
pts2 = np.array([4,5,6])
cutouts = frame[pts1,pts2]
print cutouts
#outputs [14 25 36]
```

Comment: An "integer scalar array" is something like `array(3)` - a 0-dimensional array containing a single integer. It's not an arbitrary array of integer scalars.

Comment: Please see edit 2.  Why does one example work and the other doesnt.

Comment: You can't use an array as a slice endpoint.

Comment: You have to take each (5,5) slice separately.  Collect them in a list and/or concatenate as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:  It cannot be done.  Numpy just doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

The shape of  pts[:, 0]  is (2,), so it is not a scalar
try this, it should help in your case.

```
imgfrag = img[pts[0,0]:pts[1,0], pts[0,1]:pts[1,1]]
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that fits more than just 2 points.

If I print out pts[:,0], I get a 1d array of scalars that looks like this:  
[10,30,value,value,value..]
This should meet the criteria for broadcasting.

Comment: boradcast is only meanful when you try to do calculation on 2 ndarrays. you are using pts[:, 0] as index. I don't think this is a boradcast case.